# Составление SQL запроса к 2 таблицам

Tags: php, mysql

Есть SQL запрос - `('SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = '.$category_id)`
Он выводит список продуктов из products, у которых категория = $category_id.
БД проста - таблица products и category, products.category_id связан с category.id.
Ключевой вопрос: как сделать, чтобы можно было найти продукты по названию категории, а не по ID? Т.е. сначала запрос посылается к таблице category, чтобы найти id нужной категории, а потом уже по этому id делается выборка из таблицы products. Делать 2 запроса к БД не хочется. Пытался сделать так: `('SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN category ON category.name = '.$category_name.'WHERE products.category_id = category.id')` Но поинмаю, что делаю какую-то хрень. Скажите, как это сделать 1 запросом к БД? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я понял правильно, то так:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.* 
        FROM products p 
        JOIN category cat
        ON p.category_id  = cat.id
        WHERE cat.name = '{$category_name}'";
```

то есть, как раз-таки, JOIN делаем по идентификатору категории, а условие выборки `WHERE` по имени

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все сработало :)